# How to customize editor by data type

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I made a table with `kendo-grid`.This table have two columns.one is `item`, another is `value`.

just as

```
+-----------+-----------+
| item      |  value    |
+-----------+-----------+
| Retry     |  yes      |
| interval  |  8        |
+-----------+-----------+
```

How to customize editor(inline) with value column.if value is [yes], use the dropdownlist editor, if value is [8], use the numeric edior.

Thx.

Comment: You can try to customize the `editor` option of your column(value). Here's the reference https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your convenience, I prepared a small example demonstrating such customization of kendo-grid.

Here's the example how you can customize the `editor` option of column based on the value that column contains(for example "yes" in your case):

```
function DropDownEditor(container, options) {

    if(options.model.itemvalue =="yes"){
        var input = $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        input.appendTo(container);
        input.kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: {
                data: ["yes", "no"]
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        var input = $('<input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="itemvalue" data-bind="value:itemvalue">'); 
        input.appendTo(container); 
    }
};
```

And your grid's configuration may look like:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
data:[{"item":"Retry", "itemvalue":"yes"},{"item":"interval", "itemvalue": 8}]
},    
height: 500,    
columns: [ 
  { field: "item", width: "200px"},
  { field: "itemvalue", editor: DropDownEditor }],
editable: "incell"
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

In above example the column with the editor uses the DropDownEditor function to create the editor based on the value in "itemvalue" column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @rubyblaze, glad you found it helpful. If it answers your question, pls accept it as answer, it will be helpful to others as well.